# How to know my IPv4 address

Tags: windows-7, tcp, ipv4

Recently I wrote a simple program which simulates the comunication between a Server and a Client on my computer by the TCP protocol. 
As the title say, I need to know how to obtain the IPv4 address of my Pc (Windows 7) in the simplest possible way in order to see if my program works.
Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Why?  You can't use your IPv4 address within your internal network to communicate with devices on your internal network.  Your IPv4 address only would communicate with your Router/Modem

Comment: @Ramhound: You certainly can; isn't that why hosts have a subnet mask configured? ("Client isolation" is the exception, not the rule.)

Comment: [How do I extract the IPv4 IP Address from the output of ipconfig](//superuser.com/q/1034471)

Comment: @grawity was speaking more of the author's public IPv4 address...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Guaranteed

If you have working IPv4 communications, you have at least this IP address:

- "127.0.0.1"

That might not be what you intended, but that is likely the *simplest* answer for you, so there you go.

## More

How to determining what IPv4 addresses you have will vary based on what language you are using.  If you're communicating with IP, you're likely to be using code that also offers you a way to know your IP address(es).  If you were using Batch, you could output the IP addresses to a text file using:

`WMIC /OUTPUT:"file.txt" NICCONFIG Get Caption,DefaultIPGateway,Description,IPAddress,IPSubnet,MACAddress /format:list`

(If using PowerShell, the same would work exception you would want to place a "back-quote"/"back tick" before each quotation mark and comma.)

(That example includes some optional stuff: Feel free to remove the `/OUTPUT` and `/format` sections, the usually-redundant "Description" section, and more.  If you leave off everything after "Get" except the optional "`/format:list`", you'll actually get *more* information.)

If you want an answer specific to another programming language, you should really ask that as a separate question elsewhere (I would recommend on the StackOverflow site).

With IPv4, you'll often be using (a) private address(es) (starting with "192.168." or "172.16." through "172.31." or "10.").

## Public

Some people want to know what their publicly-accessible IP address is.  *The* way to know that is to ask the Internet.  e.g., use HTTP to communicate with http://whatismyip.com or some other similar site, and perform whatever steps are necessary to extract the desired content.

## Side Note: IPv6

You didn't ask about IPv6, but IPv6 is worth not shying away from, so here is the data related to IPv6.

- You'll have ::1 as a loopback address
- While you typically do not want to have a "link local" address (starting with "169.254.") in IPv4, in IPv6 you definitely do.  Such "link local" addresses are more restrictive in nature, and the only reason you don't want one in IPv4 is because some IPv4 software tends to assume you have only one IPv4 address other than loopback.  Since IPv6 uses link-local as a standard, IPv6-aware software doesn't break just because a link-local address is used.
- Private addresses with IPv6 start with "fd".
- Both IPv4 and IPv6 use a concept called a "subnet mask", although IPv6 almost always uses the CIDR-style notation and calls this information a "prefix length".  Both terms end up being two ways to describe the same concept: how big the subnets are.  On any modern networks, the difference in "notation" is simply a matter of how the data is written.  (You can convert back and forth between IPv4 "subnet mask" notation and "CIDR-style" notation.)  Although you can use CIDR-style notation with IPv4 as well (and it's typically nicer when you do), a lot of IPv4 software still only shows the "subnet mask" notation.

Those are the only real IPv6-specific caveats that you would need to know (besides details like what an IPv6 address looks like) to have your program work well with IPv6.